# Will Angular reevaluate identical $watch expressions in the same $digest cycle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have a template in the form of:

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-if="exFn()"></div>
    <div ng-if="exFn()"></div>
</div>
```

will the ngController scope call `exFn` twice per $digest, or will the scope remember that the `exFn()` expression's new value and use it instead of reevaluating the expression?

Answer (score 2):

It will call `exFn` four times. Twice to find out the original value for each watch, then twice again to see if they are stable. This makes sense: the function could depend on external state.

Comment: The way the watch expressions are stacked up right now, angular is just going to call `exFn` twice every place it would have been called once, which seems like it would waste  a lot of processing if you put the same ngIf multiple times in an ngRepeated element.

Comment: Not if the function depends on external state. Imagine if the function's purpose would be to output something to the console, or do an XHR call, or mutate some variable.

Comment: I suppose it's a trade off of allowing people to bend the framework past its original purpose and processing, since watch expressions should in theory by idempotent.